# How to handle error message: "Error in cf[, 1L] : incorrect number of dimensions" in R when trying to complete model-averaging

Tags: r, data-modeling, mixed-models, error-messages-for

I've been stuck on a problem regarding an error message when I enter the command in for model averaging. I'm working in Rstudio ( version 1.1.383) with R (version 3.4.2) on my mac air (running on version 10.13.1).

I've successfully ran general linear mixed models that have been centred and scaled as well as zero-inflated and I'm attempting to average the four top models. Using the package MuMIn, I entered the command:

```
top<-model.avg(czm12, czm4, czm7, czm15)
```

The error message that follows states:

> Error in cf[, 1L] : incorrect number of dimensions

Why would this error occur and is there any way to address it? I'm new to R and would appreciate any help or guidance anyone has for me!

Comment: I'd suggest that it's trying to tell you that there is an incorrect number of dimensions. Have you checked that the number of dimensions is valid?

Comment: @LamarLatrell  Thanks for your response. I'm not exactly sure I know what the dimensions would be or what that refers to in this scenario... I know all of my models are using the same subset of data so that wouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was sloved by a package update provided by Kamil Barton.

Update MuMIn to version 1.40.1 from R-forge:

```
> install.packages("MuMIn", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")
```